# How to get rid of BadRequestKeyError?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am using Python 3. I have created the necessary folders. i.e. static and templates folder. Still, this code is not working. I get the following error `werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError`

**abc.py**

```py
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect
    app=Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/project/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def tryy():
        name=request.method
        name1=request.form["uname"]
        return render_template("project1.html",name=name1)

    if __name__=="__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

**project.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="uname" />
                <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**project1.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
                  href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hey there {{name}}. Nice to meet you</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is set to "" 
change it to this:
`<form action="/project/" method="GET">`